# Setting timer to reset on multipe clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem that have been bugging me for days.
I want the timer to add +2-3 seconds on every successful click on the figure and on every missed click (one that clicked anywhere, but on the box) to display some message like " You failed".
Edit: I got the timer, to start only on the first click, but after that I am not sure how to keep adding seconds on successful click.
 Here I'm applying my code:

HTML:

```
        <div id="main">
            <div>
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li>Score: <p id="score">0</p> </li>
                    <li>Time: <p id="count">3</p> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
             <div id="test" >
                 <p id="textHid"> CLICK ME!</p>
             </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
            #test {
                position:absolute;
                width:400px;
                height:400px;
                background-color:#d2fcd9;
            }
            #textHid {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
                font-size: 70px ;
            }
            #nav {
                padding: 1.05%;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #333;
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
            }

            li {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 18px;
                margin-left: 3.5%;
            }
            #count {
                display: inline
            }
            #score {
                display: inline;
            }
```

jQuery:

```
$('#test').click(function () {

    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#test'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    $div.css({
        left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
        top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),
        width: Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0.7, 1) * divWidth ),
        height: Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0.7, 1) * divHeight ),
        backgroundColor: "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")"
    });

    $('#score').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });

});

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

$('#textHid').click( function() {

    //$("#test").removeAttr("main");
    //$("#textHid").hide();
   document.getElementById('textHid').remove();
   this.remove();
});

function startTimer(){
    var counter = 3 ;
    setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        if (counter >= 0) {
            span = document.getElementById("count");
            span.innerHTML = counter;
        }

        if (counter === 0) {
            alert('sorry, out of time');
            clearInterval(counter);
        }

    }, 1000);
}


$("#test").click(function(){
    startTimer();
});
```

Comment: There are three very different questions here. I suggest taking one problem at a time, in separate questions, and try to post only code snippets relevant to that problem. It makes it much easier to read and help.

Comment: Yeah, you were right! All done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is every time you click, you create another interval and pretty sure that is not what we want.  Let just fix the design of the code, and the other issues will resolve as well.

1) I would make two buttons, one to start and initialize the game.  The other is the box you click during the game.  That way we don't get our button clicks confused and the code is easier to read.  Every time you click start, that button initializes the game and starts the timer, hides itself and shows the game box.  Every time you click the game box, you add a point and add time.

2) Store your `count` (time remaining) variable as a global variable so everyone can access it!  This version of JS (before ES6) only has functional and global scope, so where this `counter` variable is defined, it cannot be accessed from the other controls.  Declare this variable outside as a global instead.

See the following code example:

```js
$('#gameBox').click(function () {

    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#gameBox'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    $div.css({
        left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax ),
        top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax ),
        width: Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0.7, 1) * divWidth ),
        height: Math.floor(getRandomArbitrary(0.7, 1) * divHeight ),
        backgroundColor: "rgb(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + "," + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256) + ")"
    });

    $('#score').html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
    
    counter += 1;
    span = document.getElementById("count");
    span.innerHTML = counter;

});

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var counter = 3;

function startTimer(){
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        if (counter >= 0) {
            span = document.getElementById("count");
            span.innerHTML = counter;
        }

        if (counter <= 0) {
            alert('sorry, out of time');
            clearInterval(timer);
            $('#test').unbind();
            $('#gameBox').hide();
            $('#startButton').show();
            $('#startButton').text("You lost! Try again!");
            
        }
    }, 1000);
}


$("#startButton").click(function(){
    counter = 3;
    span = document.getElementById("count");
    span.innerHTML = counter;
    startTimer();
    $(this).hide();
    $('#gameBox').show();
});

$('#gameBox').hide();
```

```css
#gameBox {
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#d2fcd9;
}
#startButton {
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color:#d2d9fc;
}
#nav {
    padding: 1.05%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 3.5%;
}
#count {
    display: inline
}
#score {
    display: inline;
}
.off {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div>
        <ul id="nav">
            <li>Score: <p id="score">0</p> </li>
            <li>Time: <p id="count">3</p> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="startButton"> CLICK ME!</div>
    <div id="gameBox"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check someone is clicking on the button and not outside of it you can use [`e.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```js
$("#textHid").click(function (e) {
  // do what you want to do to 'increase' the user's score
  alert("You clicked the button!");

  // now, this is important to stop a click on the button from
  // also being a click on the elements which contain the button:
  e.stopPropagation();
});
                    
$("#main").click(function () {
  alert("Ouch, you missed the button :(");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <button id="textHid">Click me!</button>
</div>
```

If you mean *anywhere* except on the button should be a failure, you can use `$(document)` instead of `$("#main")`.